# How was vishwanathan anand?

Tags: tournament, grandmaster

I am fairly new to chess. I don’t know anything. The time I am taking interest in chess it is already proclaimed that this is the time of carlsen (except that yui person). 
I wish to know about vishwanathan anand.  For one that he was predecessor and for two that I am an Indian so I have some sort of subconscious obligation to know about him.

I want to know from you guys,  The chess community. (I can get facts on Wikipedia but I can't understand the environment and energy of his era and niether will successive generation know about carlsen) 
 How was the rise and fall of V. Anand ? Why isn't he good now ? Doesn't he has more experience which should make him better player !

Comment: Vishy has been playing top-class chess for over two decades now, and although he's getting a bit old and could be said to be past his prime, he's still rated 9th in the world; talking about "the fall" of Vishy therefore seems strange IMO.

Comment: I'm voting to close as there isn't an answerable question here. In many sports, a player/team is dominant for a time, then becomes less so. There may be various reasons (age, changing values, new kid on the block etc.) We could speculate here why Anand is no longer dominant, but that is too broad a topic.

Comment: Anand is still in the top 10. What are you talking about??

Comment: @Bad_Bishop but shouldn't experience make a chess player better ? Like it's not tennis that you need physical fitness

Comment: @SmallChess he has been playing really bad

Comment: @user154547 Bad? Played over 2750+ level, and it's bad??

Comment: @SmallChess of course I am not comparing this to you and me level. I am talking about his peers. His recent games are getting worse. Why ? Doesn't experience makes you better ?

Comment: You have to be in good shape to play top level chess. It requires stamina and your brain uses a lot of nutrients that would be used elsewhere in the body if you were in a resting state.

Comment: Like you said, you know nothing. Playing games of chess on his level for several hours a time is very taxing for the body, even if most of it isn't as visible as in other sports. And "really bad".. how would you of all people know?

Comment: Also, experience doesn't always correlate with success. An extreme example is a child prodigy beating an experienced amateur.

Comment: @Annatar sorry if I come up rude. I was just curious. No bad feel.  *sparks *sprinkles *smiles

Comment: No bad feelings from me either, don't worry. You are just making a fool out of yourself here, that's all. Like a guy stumbling into a bar when the TV shows a game of [insert sport here], sees that the one team he even knows the name of has a worse score and starts asking everyone for there reason they became "so bad", I mean, they were famous enough that he heard of them, shouldn't they win against a nameless something? Right? Oh, wait, the nameless team happens to be even more famous now to everyone who is even remotely interested in the sport? And you are just watching the finals? Damn..

Comment: @Annatar it's actually not my view. Being Indian I hold him at high regard since I was a child (not interested in chess that time but news was thing)

Comment: @Annatar I asked cuz I have heard lot of criticism of him recently.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some revelations. Firstly, chess is a sport. It's not called that by formality, it actually is a sport. It takes both physical and mental endurance to play the sport at a high level. This seems silly to anyone who has never seriously played a 6-hour game, but it does not to anyone who has been through that experience. Especially if you start dozing off at move 50 and make a blunder that pours half a day of work down the drain. Then you realize going to tournaments and doing this frequently at a much higher level must put a big strain on both body and mind.

Your mental faculties and your body both deteriorate, starting when you are around 22 years old. Experience may seem very useful in chess, but opening theory is constantly developing while the rest of the game relies on pattern recognition and calculation. These skills do not improve beyond a certain point which a player like Anand has reached decades ago. Thus, experience plays a limited role in chess and does not properly compensate for the deterioration of your mind and body. At a certain point you need to put in many hours of practice every week just to keep your skills from deteriorating, all the while your body is deteriorating regardless. In a game like chess, this is not as noticeable as in the more physical sports of course, but it is nonetheless significant and thus it is exceptional that Anand has remained in the top 10 for such a tremendously long amount of time. This is the exception, not the rule.

So instead of wondering why Anand is falling off, I would wonder why he has been able to maintain such a superb position for such an incredible amount of time. It's the exact opposite of the proposed question, which indeed comes off as a bit ignorant as people have pointed out, considering that Anand is not just "still good" but rather "still among the world elite which has been developing and growing constantly while he was getting older". It's amazing, really.

The rest of the question is a bit unclear. I have no idea how I could possibly know something about an elite player that cannot be found on the internet and I don't know what kind of specialty you expect surrounds players who sit behind a board and make good moves very consistently. Aside from the few rather strange fellows like Fischer and, to a lesser extent, Kasparov, most chess players are just people like you and me.

Comment: Was anand back in the days as revered and famous as today's chess players ?

Comment: Like carlsen e.t.c

Comment: I am too young to have been around during that time, but I would say this is almost certainly the case. An example: in the one book series I used to learn the game, there are some hand drawings of players. Aside from the national stars, Anand is featured along with other world famous players like Kasparov and Karpov. He is an active ex-world champion, after all.  It's hard to rank people like this, but he's certainly incredibly famous and regarded very highly by most of us in the chess community due to his decades of world elite performance.